# MongoChef not showing the MongoD collections

Tags: mongodb, database-connection, mongo-collection

I am new to the MongoDB and MongoChef and connecting to the MongoDB server which is not local and is setup on some remote server(for which i do not require any VPN or visual network) using the MongoChef client.

When i pass the IP in the MongoChef's New Connection tab, the "Test Connection" button return all "OK" status as follows:

[image]

But in the main window of mongochef it is not showing any collection or database. Here is the screen shot:
[image]

I tried connecting to the server from the terminal and it is connecting well. I can do ping and telnet to the server well.

I am not getting where is the problem?

Comment: I see you are supplying a user to authenticate. Unless that user has permissions to [`listCollections`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/privilege-actions/#listCollections) on the current database then you will in fact see nothing. Perhaps you should try connecting from elsewhere, such as the `mongo` shell. If you see ( or rather do not see ) the same results, then you have a permissions problem or are connecting to the wrong database. If you actually do see collections from another tool, then it's a bug with the product and should be logged in official channels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the authentication, so i needed to edit the connection and add the authentication parameters viz username, password and database name as specified in the following screenshot

[image]

Making the above changes solved the issue for me. But still, i am not sure why was the previous connections giving test OK status.